# Retrieving from ArrayList and Storing into new Arraylist using hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a ArrayList of vouchers as following.

voucherlist ArrayList

```
    [0] voucher  
        carrierCode "UPS"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L998"  
        systemVoucherID "000000000632" 
    [1] voucher  
        carrierCode "UPS"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L998"  
        systemVoucherID "000000000633"  
    [2] voucher  
        carrierCode "UPS"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L998"  
        systemVoucherID "000000000634"  
    [3] voucher  (id=2744)
        carrierCode "FEDEX" 
        originShippingLocationCode  "L998"  
        systemVoucherID "000000000638"  
    [4] voucher     
        carrierCode "FEDEX"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L998"  
        systemVoucherID "000000000639"  
    [5] voucher     
        carrierCode "UPS"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L1003"     
        systemVoucherID "000000000636"  
    [6] voucher     
        carrierCode "UPS"
        originShippingLocationCode  "L1003"     
        systemVoucherID "000000000637"  
    [7] voucher  
        carrierCode "UPS"   
        originShippingLocationCode  "L1001"     
        systemVoucherID "000000000635"
```

I have to group(create a new ArrayList) the vouchers which have same originShippingLocationCode.

Ex: all the vouchers which have originShippingLocationCode= "L998" to one new ArrayList.

I don't know what will be the value for originShippingLocationCode it will be changing. I get this data as a response from a API call.

Can any one please help in this problem?

I'm thinking to use Hashmap to create a new ArrayList when a originShippingLocationCode is detected, keeping originShippingLocationCode as a 'Key'.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use a `HashMap` for this, here is an example:

```
ArrayList<Voucher> vouchers = new ArrayList<Voucher>();
...
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Voucher>> groups = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Voucher>>();
for (Voucher v : vouchers) {
    if (groups.containsKey(v.getOriginShippingLocationCode())) {
        groups.get(v.getOriginShippingLocationCode()).add(v);
    } else {
        groups.put(v.getOriginShippingLocationCode(), new ArrayList<Voucher>(Arrays.asList(new Voucher[] { v })));
    }
}
```

Comment: My requirement is changed now.

Comment: I have to group the vouchers based on originShippingLocationCode and carrierCode. Can you help me in this problem? @Titus

Comment: @vijay.k you can concatenate those values into a single `String` and use that has the map's key.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can gather, you want to search your current array and pull out all of the vouchers that have a specific shipping location?

You can do that using something similar to the following

```
 for (Voucher v : vouchers) {
     if (v.getOriginShippingLocationCode().equals("L998")) {
         //.. add to new array list
     }
 }
```

This will loop through all your vouchers and compare its shipping location code to the one you specify. If it matches, you can do what you like with it.

**Edit**:

If you don't know the shipping location (I must have missed that part from your op), you can use a map and have your shipping location as the key perhaps so you can just get all the vouchers related to a specific location.

```
Map<String, List<Voucher>> vouchers = new HashMap<>();
```

Build your new list based on the key, then `vouchers.put(key, newList);`

Comment: The question states "I don't know what will be the value for originShippingLocationCode it will be changing." so that will not be very useful.

Comment: The better way is what the OP already suggested. "I'm thinking to use Hashmap to create a new ArrayList when a originShippingLocationCode is detected, keeping originShippingLocationCode as a 'Key'."